# how to access resources in maven project?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, maven

I've got an purely-javascript webapp mavin project, and I need to load an xml file from the resources folder via the function:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send(null);
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

where 'dname' is a string that represents the xml file's path.

This function is in my sources files (src/main/javascript) and I'd like to get the xml from the resources folder (src/main/resources).  What's the best way to do this? Should I modify the pom.xml in some way?

Answer (score 0):

What packaging/plugin is being used to build the project.  Is it the [Javascript Maven Tools plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/) from Codehaus?

If so, resources are written to `${project.build.outputDirectory}` (which defaults to target/classes) and javascript files are written to `${project.build.outputDirectory}/js`.  So, relative to your JS files, resources are at `../<resourcename>`.

These settings are controlled from the [js-import-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-maven-plugin/) which is invoked from Javascript Maven Tools plugin during the build.